# Not getting ClientID in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clientid

I have ASP.Net page where i am calling a JavaScript function like this:

```
 Enter server name: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btn_view" runat="server" OnClick="View_btn_click" OnClientClick="return  AlertOnGo('View Configuration',document.getElementById('<%= txt_name.ClientID %>').value)" Text ="GO!" />
```

But on clicking the GO button, i am getting the following error:

**JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference**

On viewing the rendered code for the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_view" value="GO!" onclick="return AlertOnGo('View Configuration',document.getElementById('<%= txt_name.ClientID %>').value);" id="btn_view" />
```

It is not putting the appropriate ClientID. I tried setting the CLientIDMode to static for the test box, yet no help.

This question is similar to this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147906/issue-getting-clientid-in-asp-net-c-sharp).

Comment: I think that this occurs because when you render your asp.net textbox control, he was a different id, and not what you see when editing html..

Comment: Look if this can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844675/asp-net-document-getelementbyid-control-clientid-returns-null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this problem.

One of the simpler would be to move the name into a JavaScript variable since the problem only occurs within the control when trying to evaluate txt_name.ClientID inside the OnClientClick attribute of an ASP.NET control.

```
<script>
var txtName = '<%= txt_name.ClientID %>';
</script>

Enter server name: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btn_view" runat="server" OnClick="View_btn_click" 
OnClientClick="return  AlertOnGo('View Configuration', 
document.getElementById(txtName).value)" Text ="GO!" />
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use the property `ClientIDMode="Static"` inside the asp:textbox tag

like this

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn_view" runat="server" OnClick="View_btn_click" 
 OnClientClick="return  AlertOnGo('View Configuration', 
 document.getElementById(txtName).value)" Text ="GO!" />
```

this way the client id of the text box would be same as the "id" and you can use 
     `document.getElementById('txt_name').value`

and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

-- edited answer --
aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_view" runat="server" OnClick="View_btn_click" OnClientClick="javascript:return  AlertOnGo('View Configuration');" Text ="GO!" />
```

script

```
function AlertOnGo(mode)
{
  var btnId = '<%= txt_name.ClientID %>';
  var value=document.getElementById(btnId).value;

//your code

return false;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Same problem. The part `<%= txt_name.ClientID %>` is not executing and rendering as it is on webpage.

Comment: I think that would work. But i need to call the same JavaScript function with different textbox ID's and hence need to move that part out of it. See Jacob's answer above. It works, by setting the txtName each time before calling the AlertOnGo function.

Answer (score 0):

Youre using <%= %> in the property of an asp.net web control - I wouldnt expect that to work, since the whole control will be replaced by html.

I would move your javascript out into a script block and attach the event handler in code rather than putting it all inline.

```
Enter server name: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btn_view" runat="server" OnClick="View_btn_click" Text ="GO!" />
<script>
document.getElementById('<%= btn_view.ClientID %>').attachEvent('click', function() {
     return AlertOnGo('View Configuration',
                        document.getElementById('<%= txt_name.ClientID %>').value);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use String.Concat. You can use \u0027 instead of apostrophe.

```
OnClientClick='<%#String.Concat("document.getElementById(\u0027", AddToCartBtn.ClientID.ToString(), "\u0027).value = \u0027Adding...\u0027;")%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is you can go to browser do insect element read the dynamic Id of textbox and set that in javascript like:

```
var ddlFunction = document.getElementById('ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ecede3f6_2b87_405a_af1b_70401bb8d4c7_ddlFunction');
```

Html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFunction" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownClass">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sample 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sample 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class and use that instead of client id, (with jQuery $('.txt_name').text()):

Enter server name:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" CssClass="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```