# Retrieving Client side ID in asp.net for javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For a website A usercontrol (ascx) has been defined to do a calculation assist for the user.
The control is implemented multiple times in another ascx control which is part of an umbraco website.

Some of the panels in the user control have been hidden, and i am trying to display them through the use of java script.

the asp code for selecting a panel to show:

```
<asp:Panel ID="firstpanel" runat="server">
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelect" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >
     <asp:ListItem Text="Show hidden" Value="0" onclick="ShowMe('<%= hiddenPan.ClientID %>');" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Show other" Value="1" onclick="ShowMe('<%= otherPan.ClientID %>');" ></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="hiddenPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
  <!-- stuff to work with -->
</asp:Panel>
```

the javascript code is as following:

```
function ShowMe(showPanel) {
    console.log(showPanel);
    $('#' + showPanel).show();
}
```

This method does not work. The console log returns the value **<%= hiddenPan.ClientID %>**  instead of the clientID that I would expect.

solutions I've tried:
implementing static client IDs -> since the ascx control is implemented multiple times, this would cause the javascript to show and hide the first control it finds, not the active control.

I have tried the solution found in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147288/not-getting-clientid-in-asp-net) but it did not work for me.

My question is how can I toggle the display of the panel in the example. A good work around is also welcome.

Comment: This is strange. Can you check and see if this code is dynamically run under IIS?

Comment: Would I be able to see that in the IIS?

Comment: If this piece of code is running inside an `ASPX` page, and that page is inside a Virtual Directory that is defined as an application, then yes.

Comment: I checked, yes it is dynamically run

Comment: This was a silly question I asked! Excuse me. I'm trying to find a way

Answer (score 0):

****Edited****

I'm not sure but maybe it's because ListItem property that convert all value to string, check this:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="<%= hiddenPan.ClientID %>" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
```

You can see that Text is shown as `<%= hiddenPan.ClientID %>` too.

You can try this if it's not conflict with the real project, this works exactly as you want:

```
<div class="divUserControlContainer">
    <asp:Panel ID="firstpanel" runat="server">
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelect" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >
         <asp:ListItem Text="Show hidden" Value="0" onclick="ShowMe(this.id,'hiddenPan');" ></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Show other" Value="1" onclick="ShowMe(this.id,'otherPan');" ></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="hiddenPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
        <!-- stuff to work with -->
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="otherPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
        <!-- stuff to work with -->
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function ShowMe(thisId, showPanel) {
    console.log(showPanel);
    $('#' + showPanel).show();
    $('#' + thisId).closest('.divUserControlContainer').find("div[id*='" + showPanel + "']").show();
}
```

The only thing is that each PanelID should not be as a substring of another PanelID and also wrap each UserControl with a `div` with this class: `divUserControlContainer`.

Comment: This will only work if the client ID mode is set to static.   ClientIDMode ="static", and only for the first control. The second control will not work.

Comment: No it's not, you don't need to set `ClientIDMode ="static"` and it's work for second control too, please check the answer's codes before writing comments.

Comment: It works for all the panels, not just the one. I am dealing with multiple instances of the same usercontrol, and this unhides the panels in each of them.

Comment: I completely understand your problem after your last comment, i edit answer, you can check the new answer, in the edited code each usercontrol work separately, when you click on `ListItem` the jquery search for his `divUserControlContainer` container and when find it, ONLY show the selected panel in the same `divUserControlContainer` and don't change other `divUserControlContainers` (read other `UserControls`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use other workaround using `JQuery`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="firstpanel" runat="server">
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelect" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >
     <asp:ListItem Text="Show hidden" Value="0"   ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Show other" Value="1"   ></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="hiddenPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
  <!-- stuff to work with -->here some content
</asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="otherPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
  <!-- stuff to work with -->here some more content
</asp:Panel>
```

on jQuery side:

```
/// $("[id*=rblSelect] input").live("click", function () { -- old jquery way

// new version of Jquery uses 'on' instead of 'live'
$("[id*=rblSelect]").on("click", "input", function () 
{ 
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     if (selectedValue == "0") // IF first item is clicked
     {
          $('#' + '<%=hiddenPan.ClientID %>').show();
     } else {
         $('#' + '<%=otherPan.ClientID %>').show();
     }
 });
```

Comment: what happened? can you please elaborate? as I have made a sample here and its run fine

Comment: I added the code to the Javascript page. I added some console logging, but they did not show up on firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the ASP.NET parser encodes the quotes to their HTML equivalent if they are used inside some attributes like a ListItem's 'onclick' attribute. (I don't exactly know the behavior, but this is one case).

To solve your problem, I suggest this workaround: put just the control's name in `onclick` attribute, then in control's `OnPreRender` method find that control and create a variable with its client ID. I've chosen `PreRender` because the client IDs are all assigned before this point.

In the control's markup, just put the panel's server side Id:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Show hidden" Value="0" onclick="hiddenPan"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Show other" Value="1" onclick="otherPan" ></asp:ListItem>
```

In `Control`'s Code behind:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        foreach (ListItem i in rblSelect.Items)
        {
            string relatedControlId = i.Attributes["onclick"];

            Control relatedControl = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relatedControlId) && (relatedControl = FindControl(relatedControlId)) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("var {0}_id = '{0}';", relatedControl.ClientID);
                i.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("ShowMe({0}_id)", relatedControl.ClientID);
            }
        }
        sb.Append("</script>");
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), string.Format("ids{0}", this.ID) , sb.ToString());

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

this will add to the rendered output HTML, a variable for each of the `ListItem`s like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var uc1_hiddenPan_id = 'uc1_hiddenPan';</script>
```

and changes every `onclick` attribute for that list items to something like this:

```
 onclick="ShowMe(uc1_hiddenPan_id);"
```

UPDATE: I've edited the answer to work with more than one control as the OP requested.

Comment: Unfortunatly this method will always show and hide the panels on the first user control of the page, never the second.

Comment: I finally understood the problem. You should move the code to the control's `PreRender` event. Will you test it till I return from the barber's?

Comment: @martijn I've updated the answer. It works as you want. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've gotten it working through javascript at the client side with the following modifications:

```
<div id="containerDiv">
  <asp:Panel ID="firstpanel" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelect" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >
       <asp:ListItem Text="Show hidden" Value="0" onclick="ShowMe($$(this, 'hiddenPan'));" ></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Show other" Value="1" onclick="ShowMe($$(this, 'otherPan'));" ></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </asp:Panel>

  <asp:Panel ID="hiddenPan" runat="server" style="display:none">
    <!-- stuff to work with -->
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

javascript/client side functions:

```
function ShowMe(showPanel) {
   showPanel.show();
}

function $$(target, id) {

    var t = $(target);
    var con = t.closest("#containerDiv");
    var el = $("#" + id, con);
    if (el.length < 1)
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", con);

    return el;
}
```

The following [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery) was used to come to the solution.