# JavaScript not executing on a ASP.net webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery to create a a container that looks very similar to a tabbed panel. I have tested this feature in notepad++ multiple times and it worked. However when i recreate it in my asp.net projet the JavaScript code is note executed. There are no error within the Javascript code.
Here is my file structure

```
(folder)CSS
     Style.css
(folder)JavaScript
     jquery-1.11.0.min.js
     Tabbed_pannel.js
(folder)Images
template.Master
Web.config
packages.config
Default.aspx
page1.aspx
page2.aspx
page3.aspx
page4.aspx
```

The code i used to link the file jquery-1.11.0.min.js and Tabbed_pannel.js to Default.aspx is

```
 <script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="JavaScript/Tabbed_pannel.js"></script>
```

Is this code incorrect ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147288/not-getting-clientid-in-asp-net maybe?

Comment: try '/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'. This would give you the relative path to your application url

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/697660/1316573

Comment: Does JQuery work in the page? Could be tested by inserting some very basic JQuery code.