# Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference for hidden field

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden field control on my ascx page. I am using javascript to get the value of the selected items in my SharePoint list. The script I am using :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PtIN.png)

But I am getting error :

**Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference**

So I tried using hidden field id

```
document.getElementById("<%= ctl00_ctl34_g_77ca6479_f702_423d_a0fd_02b41917d2b6_HdnFldSelectedItemID.ClientID %>").value = selectedItems;
```

which I got from debugger tool. But, still I am getting the same error.

Any suggestion?

The html markup :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IybMA.png)

And the script is running after page load , because I am getting the selected value id in the alert but not able to set it in hidden field.

Comment: is this a id `<%= ctl00_ctl34_g_77ca6479_f702_423d_a0fd_02b41917d2b6_HdnFldSelectedItemID.ClientID %>` ?

Comment: `ctl00_ctl34_g_77ca6479_f702_423d_a0fd_02b41917d2b6_HdnFldSelectedItemID` is your client id and `HdnFldSelectedItemID` is your server id. Use `document.getElementById("<%= HdnFldSelectedItemID.ClientID %>").value = selectedItems;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not getting ClientID in ASP.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147288/not-getting-clientid-in-asp-net)

Comment: but dude i used that HdnFldSelectedItemID if u see the image that i posted first but still got the same error @Rajesh

Comment: try, `document.getElementById(<%= HdnFldSelectedItemID.ClientID %>).value = selectedItems;` without quotes once.

Comment: @johnWick First, when someone request for code, please share the code and **not**  screenshot of code(*part of your .html*). Second please try to load srcipt at the end or `window.load` method to confirm if you are not trying to access DOM before its available

Comment: @Rajesh, first comment is different from mine. I asked him to try without doubleQuotes. `document.getElementById(<%= HdnFldSelectedItemID.ClientID %>)`