# How to use generated ID's in code behind ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to hide or show section of my webpage. The problem is that the css Id's are created in the code behind. I do not know how to access them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the fonction ShowColumn KanbanColum should be collapseSection0, collapseSection1 ....  And  collapseSection collapseDiv0, collapseDiv1 .... but I cant access them. since does variables are created in the background.

```
        protected void ShowColumn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            kanbanColumn.Visible = true;
            collapseSection.Visible = false; 
        }


        public void PopulateLists(int numberOfColumns,List<string> lstColumnsNames, List<int> lstTaskPerColumns, List<string> lstTaskText,  List<string> headerColorOptions)
        {
           HtmlGenericControl li;
            string colorChosen;

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl CollapseDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                CollapseDiv.ID = "collapseSection" + j;
                CollapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "collapsed-kanban");
                CollapseDiv.Style.Add("background-color", "#f4ce46");
                dragListColumns.Controls.Add(CollapseDiv);

                ImageButton expanImage = new ImageButton();
                expanImage.ImageUrl= "~/images/maximize.png";
                expanImage.ID = "expandImageId" + j;
                expanImage.Height = 20;
                expanImage.Width = 20;
                expanImage.Attributes.Add("class", "second-menu-icon");
                expanImage.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "ShowColumn");
                CollapseDiv.Controls.Add(expanImage);


                Label lblCollapse = new Label();
                lblCollapse.Text = lstColumnsNames[j];
                lblCollapse.Attributes.Add("class", "vertical-text");
                CollapseDiv.Controls.Add(lblCollapse);

            }
}
```

Here is a image to visual represent the code.
[image: What I want to hide and show]

What can I do to be able to use the cssId's that I have created in the background or is there another way to do around the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. When exactly do you want to hide or show this section? Using Javascript, are you talking about? If you always give your elements the same class, then you could access them via the class in your Javascript

Comment: I am not using any javascript I want on button click to hide or show elements in page. Using id.Visible=true/false. I will add image to make it more clear.

Comment: Am I to understand that ShowColumn will be run on a subsequent postback? You should be aware that dynamically created elements like this do not persist between postbacks in ASP.NET webforms. Next time your code runs, they don't exist any more (at least not unless you re-run the PopulateLists function before you try to do anything else). But to be honest if it's a simple show/hide action it would be a lot more user-friendly and efficient to do it with JavaScript, and avoid unnecessary trips to the server and back for such a simple action.

Comment: I am very open minded and willing to use javascript. However I am not very familiar with javascript. How can I hide or show sections with javascript for a list of elements with de same id + a number.

Comment: google "javascript accordion" and you'll get dozens of examples. But maybe take a JavaScript tutorial first and get to know the language. As a web developer it's a vital skill these days.

Comment: Also, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147288/not-getting-clientid-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean that you find different IDs on the generated web page than the ones you define in codebehind?

You might want to take a look at the [ClientIDMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8) property of asp net tags.

If you don't specify it clearly, ASP.NET generates some weird IDs for your html.

Check [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108887/Client-Ids-Generation-with-ASP-NET-4-0) article and see if it's what you're looking for.

**If you want to manage the ids from the page side, you NEED javascript.
Use JQuery to easily access the ids**